# save 3d effect as preset?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d

How can I save custom 3d effect (just degrees and perspective) as a preset to use in other projects and easily reapply? I know that if I make a 3d effect i can go to effect-> apply rotate. But I need a better solution.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Graphic Styles**](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/graphic-styles.html)

> A graphic style is a set of reusable appearance attributes. Graphic styles allow you to quickly change the look of an object; for example, you can change its fill and stroke color, alter its transparency, and apply effects in one step. All the changes you apply with graphic styles are completely reversible.

Save an object's appearance as a Graphic Style, and just like brushes, swatches, etc., you can load the Styles in other documents and click to apply them.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of that!